# Typescript handleEvent definition

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
class myClass {
    private handleEvent(e: Event) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    constructor() {
        document.body.addEventListener(`click`, this);
    }
}
```

How to declare correctly without errors?

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "click", listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent) => any'.
      Type 'myClass' is not assignable to type '(this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent) => any'.
        Type 'myClass' provides no match for the signature '(this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent): any'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
      Type 'myClass' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
        Type 'myClass' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerObject'.
          Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerObject'.
            Type 'myClass' is not assignable to type 'EventListenerObject'.
              Property 'handleEvent' is private in type 'myClass' but not in type 'EventListenerObject'.
'handleEvent' is declared but its value is never read.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&strict=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEC2CeBhcVoG8CwAoavoAcAnASwDcwAXAU2gAswA7AExCoFFSqGKAKKgLmgcuFAJTpseKdGAB7BhFmsAdCFkBzPqMl4AvjtxyFFQgFdgFWYR7jMOabiazgp2COUAjWU3jKwTJmFuABliCGoGKmsAA1BiYABraIAaaApaMNEAbgNofSxdIA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `function` as your handler. `this` points to your `myClass` and not the function `handleEvent` inside it.

Try the below :-

```
class myClass {
    private handleEvent(e: Event) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    constructor() {
        document.body.addEventListener(`click`, this.handleEvent);
    }
}
```

This can be inferred from your error output line :-

`Type 'myClass' is not assignable to type '(this: HTMLElement, ev: MouseEvent) => any'.`

Based on your comment, `handleEvent` should be `public` instead of `private` as pointed by this error line :-

`Property 'handleEvent' is private in type 'myClass' but not in type 'EventListenerObject'.`

```
class myClass {
    public handleEvent(e: Event) {
        console.log(e)
    }
    constructor() {
        document.body.addEventListener(`click`, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: handleEvent is a magical function. https://dev.to/rikschennink/the-fantastically-magical-handleevent-function-1bp4